# How to Get *All* Errors When Validating XSD Schema using MSXML

Tags: xml, vbscript, xsd, xsd-validation

I've implemented XSD schema validation in VBScript using MSXML 6.0. The issue I have is that it only gets the first error. It seems that's just the way the MSXML Validate method has been implemented but I'd like to be sure -
Is there a way to get all the errors?

For example when validating using Notepad++ XML Tools it displays:
[image: XML Tools validation results]

The function below returns only the first error (Element 'preserved_surrender_amount': '' is not a valid value of the atomic type 'amount_type'.)

```vb
Function ValidateXmlAgainstSchema(xmlDoc, xsdFile)
  Dim xmlDoc
  Set xmlDoc = Sys.OleObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")
  Call xmlDoc.load(filePath)
  xmlDoc.async = False
  xmlDoc.validateOnParse = False
  xmlDoc.resolveExternals = False

  ' Open XSD file
  Set objXSD = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")
  objXSD.async = False
  Call objXSD.Load(xsdFile)

  ' Populate schema cache
  Set objSchemaCache = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLSchemaCache.6.0")

  namespace = ""
  Call objSchemaCache.Add(namespace, xsdFile)

  ' XSD XML Bind
  Set xmlDoc.Schemas = objSchemaCache

  'Check for errors
  Set objErr = xmlDoc.Validate()
  If objErr.errorCode <> 0 Then
      sResult = "Error parser: " & objErr.errorCode & "; " & objErr.reason
      Call Log.Error("Schema validation failed.", sResult)
      ValidateXmlAgainstSchema = False
  Else
      sResult = "No errors found"
      Call LogCheckpointAndAddToTestRailComment("Schema validation successful.", "")
      ValidateXmlAgainstSchema = True
  End If
End Function
```

Related: [MSXML Validate Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms756003(v%3Dvs.85))

Answer (score 0):

You want to access the [`allErrors`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms763826%28v%3dvs.85%29) object which is an [`IXMLDOMParseErrorCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms763769%28v%3dvs.85%29) collection.

> To retrieve multiple validation errors, you must enable `MultipleErrorMessages` on the DOM. To do so, you must explicitly set the `MultipleErrorMessages` parameter to `True`.
>
> ```vb
> xmlDoc.setProperty("MultipleErrorMessages", True)
> ```

Once you can access the `allErrors` collection object you can iterate over the various errors like so;

```vb
For Each error in xmlDoc.parseError.allErrors
  sResult = "Error parser: " & error.errorCode & "; " & error.reason
  Call Log.Error("Schema validation failed.", sResult)
Next
```